# Open Android App with custom URL scheme

Tags: android, sms, chromium

this questions has been asked in a similar way like a hundred times, though I still cannot find a proper answer to get my app to work the way I want. Maybe this is not possible which would be a valid answer of course.

I have an activity defined as follows in my app:

```
    <activity
        android:name="MyActivity"
        android:label="MyActivityLabel"
        android:launchMode="singleTask" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="MyActivityCustomUrlScheme" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

When I start my App in the emulator and then open the browser and type a URL like:

```
MyActivityCustomUrlScheme://mycustomHost.com?someOptions
```

the only thing happening is that chrome tries googling for it, which is not what I want. If I send myself an SMS with this scheme, the scheme inside is not recognised as such and not clickable :(

I want to do that, because I already have an iOS App in the store, which uses the scheme MyActivityCustomUrlScheme://mycustomHost.com?someOptions and it would be a lot of hazel to change it everywhere, as users get this url send by email or SMS. I'd be really thankful if someone can help me out on this problem.

Comment: Web browsers are apps, written by programmers. Those programmers can do whatever they want. If they choose -- for links or the address bar -- to not honor custom schemes, that is their choice. In my experience, neither Chrome nor Firefox do a good job with custom schemes. Not even the old AOSP Browser app supported custom schemes in the address bar, IIRC, because no user is expected to be typing in one of those manually.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @CommonsWare. What about the custom URL not showing properly in a message, so that it is actually clickable?

Comment: There is no requirement for SMS clients to interpret a random series of characters as somehow being a URL. There is no requirement for an email app, receiving a plain-text email, to interpret a random series of characters as somehow being a URL. This is why, on Android, the general recommendation is to use `http` and tie your app to your domain, as more apps will recognize such strings as actually being URLs and will make them clickable. Chrome and Firefox, last I tested, still handle such URLs internally within their browsers, though.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use definition of `host` :

```
    <activity android:name="MyActivity" 
            android:label="MyActivityLabel" 
            android:launchMode="singleTask">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="MyActivityCustomUrlScheme" android:host="mycustomHost.com" />
            </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: doesnt work either. I guess if the scheme is not treated as a scheme than the host is also ignored.